# Can Mqtt publish response and Mqtt subscribe messages get mixed up?

Tags: mqtt, microcontroller

I am writing an mqtt client on a microcontroller. It connects through an LTE modem and connects to a mqtt broker. I am using the tcp/ip stack and mqtt stack on the LTE modem. I connected the LTE modem to my uart, and I parse the data I receive.

The "driver" part where I sent commands to the modem to connect to an mqtt broker is the easy part. It gets ugly when I am online and operational. Then I send (publish) messages periodically and at the same time I can respond to "server requests" which I am subscribed to.

Thus, whenever I publish a message to the broker, theoretically I could receive a subscription message from the broker "at the same time" (just before or after I receive a response to my publish request).

How do I typically deal with this? What are the best practices to deal with this?

Some examples to clarify my problem:

mqtt start :

```
Send: AT+CMQTTSTART
Receive: [CR][NL]OK[CR][NL]

[CR] = \r
[NL] = \n
```

Since mqtt broker doesn't know I exist yet, I don't have to worry about any bytes being send "unexpectedly". So until I am subscribing to topics, all is easy.

But when I start to publish something, after I successfully subscribed to some topics, the following possibilities are a bit trickier to deal with:

```
Send: AT+CMQTTTOPIC=0,3
Receive: [CR][NL]>                    This is the expected reply for the given command
Receive: [CR][NL]+CMQTTRXSTART:....   This is the start of a published message
```

Of course the order could even be the other way around. And if the published message would be long enough, so that it gets chopped up in different packets, the response to my topic command could end up somewhere in between of the published message packets.

I have the feeling I am doing something wrong which gets me in this overly complicated situation. Since mqtt is supposed to be "simple", I must be doing something wrong.

Hope somebody can help me out a bit!

Comment: "Of course the order could even be the other way around" have you actually seen this?

Comment: No, that's a bit hard to test/debug, but the messages are published asynchronous so I imagine any order is possible

Comment: No, the broker won't send messages out of order and the it will always send the response to the subscription request before any of the matching messages.

Comment: Are you actually seeing a problem with your implementation or is all this just theoretical?

Comment: If I start to define a topic, I get a prompt returned from the broker where I need to specify the characters that define the topic. At that moment (before my MCU replied with the actual topic name), I publish a message from the broker to my MCU. That's what I have "enforced". And that's where my question arised. If I can enforce this behavior (and thus have to carefully check which message I receive from the brooker to check if it belongs to something I requested or if it belongs to some published message) then I imagine I can also have the situation where the published message is timed.......

Comment: ... at the same time I was publishing. And then it would be possible to receive the published subscription message while I was expecting the "prompt reply". The broker can't control "what he already sent", right?

Comment: So yes, the latter, is purely theoretical. I need to know how careful I need to be with interpreting what I receive over uart.

Comment: The broker doesn't send any prompts, that is purely an artefact of the MQTT client in the hardware you are using. And yes you will always have to explicitly check any input you get

Comment: Ah right, that makes perfect sense. Sorry didn't realize that this indeed is only related to how I use the LTE modem. If I move away from using their mqtt stack and use the modem in ppp mode with lwip, I don't have this problem. OK, I need to think on this a bit longer. Thanks for pointing this out though

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. MQTT Packets comes with the information regarding the packet type(PUBACK, SUB, PINGRESP etc.) so that you process them accordingly, Also if that is not enough for your application there is also 2 byte field called Message Identifier to let you know exactly which publish/subscribe packet you are getting your response for.

I suggest you to take a look at the standard;
https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/mqtt-v5.0.pdf